# How do I take information inputted by user in my app to a web-based app and then get the results from the web-based app back to my app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am a complete beginner with Swift programming, so when answering this question, please try to keep it simple! Thank you!!

I am creating an iOS app on Swift. The user will input some data - for example, a date of birth. There is this web-based app that collects information, does some calculations, and then outputs a response from that information. The web-based app is not my own. Essentially, I want the information that the user enters in my app to go to this other web-based app. After the web-based app returns a response, I want that response to go back to my app and be given to the user.

I'm not really sure where to start. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: This doesn't seem like a project for a "complete beginner". I would recommend picking something a bit simpler so you can learn to walk before you try to run. That said, you usually can't connect a native app to a web app unless they provide an API, so if you decide to go through with this project you could start by looking for that service's API.

Comment: Thank you - I'm starting to realize that I may have bitten off a little too much.

I think their API is "BGEN lib". Does that sound right?